# SwiftLint integration on Xcode 7.3.1, and getting error on --config command for .yml file configuration

Tags: ios, xcode7, swiftlint

I have integrated SwiftLint using pods and its working fine to produce warnings and errors. But I want to configure .yml file. For this I use following command on terminal.

swiftlint lint --config MyFile.yml

and getting following error...

fatal error: Loading sourcekitd.framework/Versions/A/sourcekitd failed: file /Users/marcelofabri/Westfield/SwiftLint/Carthage/Checkouts/SourceKitten/Source/SourceKittenFramework/library_wrapper.swift, line 61
Illegal instruction: 4

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Hello Mohsin.. did you get any solution ? i am facing the same problem when trying to run 'swiftlint autocorrect' . :(

Answer (score 21):

This issue may occurred, because command line tool is not set in xcode. To solve the issue.

```
Xcode->preference->select Location Tab
```

In the "Command Line Tools" menu select the appropriate xcode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got similar error when using https://github.com/Brightify/Cuckoo "SourceKittenFramework/library_wrapper.swift:66: Fatal error: Loading sourcekitd.framework/Versions/A/sourcekitd failed". This solves it too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve the issue using Terminal:

```bash
sudo xcode-select --reset
```